# "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 in Python Flask

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, export-to-excel

This is my code i m getting error on browser is The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. my file name is app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request

from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

app = Flask(__name__)

x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=12, minute=52, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

secs=delta_t.seconds+1

def hello_world():
print "hello world"
#...

t = Timer(secs, hello_world)
t.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(port=5004)
```

Comment: you need to define a route, i.e. add `@app.route('/')` above your hello_world  function

Comment: actually i did that but problem is that as i m setting a particular timing to print but it is not printing that time.when i run my file on my console it print on correct time but in  browser it just display but not at the correct time

Answer (score 4):

Before your `hello_world` function add `@app.route('/')` such that your code looks as follows,

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print "hello world"
```

Comment: actually i did that but problem is that as i m setting a particular timing to print but it is not printing that time.when i run my file on my console it print on correct time but in browser it just display but not at the correct time

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request

from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

app = Flask(__name__)

x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=13, minute=05, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

secs=delta_t.seconds+1

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
print "hello world"
#...

t = Timer(secs, hello_world)
t.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.debug = True
app.run(port=5002)